# Remove all lines without an @ character in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a list like:

```
asd@asd
abcdefgh
abcde@fgh
ijklmnop
```

I want to remove all lines without the symbol `@`. The result should be:

```
 asd@asd
 abcde@fgh
```

Can this be done in Notepad++, and if so, how?

Comment: You might have to whip up a bit of regex to help you out, dood.

Comment: I already looked on this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression i can find the @ smybol with [A-Za-z0-9]@[A-Za-z0-9] but I only can change them and not remove the others.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try looking for:

```
^[^@]*$
```

and replacing with an empty string.

Comment: Wow thats awesome ... I will try it !

Comment: Yes, try with this regular expression. It removes all the lines with that do not contain at least an @

Comment: @Notepadguy - That regex means "a full line that doesn't contain @"

Comment: Worked Great, Thanks Xtracto & Ryan Gross

Comment: If you want to remove the entire line in one shot with Find/Replace, make your regex `^[^@]*\r\n` (\r\n is for a Windows text file, in NP++ check with View -> Show Symbol to find actual new line characters)

Answer (score 2):

Use find and replace with the following regular expression:

```
^[^@]*$
```

Answer (score 1):

In the search window, goto the "Mark" tab (If it is missing, you need to upgrade your Notepad++).

Select "Bookmark Line" and "Regular Expression", use the regular expression you already got

```
^[^@]*$
```

Press "Mark all"

This results in bookmarks for all Lines with no `@`.

Goto the menu point "Search - Bookmark -> "Remove Bookmarked Lines"".